# How to conditional break line in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I conditionally add line break to HTML button/s?

I have button like this:

```
+----------------+
| Button Clicked |
|      (5)       |
+----------------+
```

Now I have condition that if I set the hide text of button it will hide the  text "Button Clicked" only and set the text "(5)" to vertically and horizontally centered. It should be like this:

```
+---------------+
|               |
|      (5)      |
|               |
+---------------+
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<button style="text-align:center; overflow: hidden;" class="btn btn-primary">
     {{btnClicked == 'hide' ? '' : 'Button Clicked'}} <br /> ({{clckCount}})
</button>
```

I tried this:

```
<button style="text-align:center; overflow: hidden;" class="btn btn-primary">
         {{btnClicked == 'hide' ? '' : 'Button Clicked <br />'}} ({{clckCount}})
</button>
```

but it print/shows my code to button.

Comment: What language is this, Javascript?

Comment: Are you using some kind of a html template?

Comment: Yes, javascript. I pass the hide value to btnClicked. and the clckCount is the number of button clicked

Comment: That's neither valid html or valid JavaScript. You can't have code there. As you mention, the browser will not run that code, just display as text.

Comment: @heero I am using bootstrap.

Comment: My first HTML code is working. But I don't know where to put the line break on my condition.

Comment: Can you tell us what JavaScript framework you're using that provides this template syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found the solution. I added condition on my `<br />`.

```
<br ng-if="btnClicked == 'hide' ? false : true" />
```

Here's my updated code:

```
<button style="text-align:center; overflow: hidden;" class="btn btn-primary">
         {{btnClicked == 'hide' ? '' : 'Button Clicked'}} <br ng-if="btnClicked == 'hide' ? false : true" /> ({{clckCount}})
</button>
```

This will disable the `<br />` tag when the button text is hidden and enable if not.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not a templating framework, it is javascript. The code in your double mustache syntax is what the commenters are asking about.

It doesn't look like Handlebars or Blade because you didn't put a #if statement in. It does look like Vue.js.

In Vue.js, however, you should put the condition in the `v-if` attribute.

```
<span v-if="'hide' == btnClicked">Button Clicked <br /></span> ({{clckCount}})
```